# FFmpeg not closing output file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to write video frames to a file.

So far I'm able to create an output file, grab my frames from a camera, encode the frames, write them and close the output file.

Everything works great except that I need to close my program for the output file to be available to be played. Closing the file is not enough.

If I don't close my program the output file shows as a 0KB file.

This is my output file closing code:

```
if (outContext)
{
    int ret = av_write_frame(outContext, NULL);
    ret = av_write_trailer(outContext);
    if (outContext->pb)
    {
        av_freep(&outContext->pb->buffer);
        av_freep(&outContext->pb);
        avio_close(outContext->pb);
    }
    avformat_free_context(outContext);
}
```

Am I forgetting to free/close anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can name a few possible improvements:

1) It's not necessary to use this line of code:

```
int ret = av_write_frame(outContext, NULL);
```

because `av_write_trailer` flushes any buffered packets.

2) Also these two lines:

```
av_freep(&outContext->pb->buffer);
av_freep(&outContext->pb);
```

are redundant because they're partially duplicate `avio_close` functionality.

In fact, the most possible reason is that `avio_close` needs a valid pointer to `AVIOContext` as an argument. When you manually doing

```
av_freep(&outContext->pb);
```

`outContext->pb` becomes null and `avio_close` doesn't work properly.

Comment: I took you suggestions, since it was redundant, and my problem got solved!
The problem was this line: `av_freep(&outputDetails->outContext->pb);`